# query for get all string date in ASC order from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get all date in ASC order which are mentioned formatted by sql query in php.

if the stored dates is-

```
01-Mar-2017
08-Feb-2017
10-Aug-2017
10-Dec-2016
18-Jan-2017
29-Nov-2015
21-Oct-2018
30-Aug-2017
13-Feb-2017
```

Result will like this-:

```
29-Nov-2015
10-Dec-2016
18-Jan-2017
08-Feb-2017
13-Feb-2017
01-Mar-2017
10-Aug-2017
30-Aug-2017
21-Oct-2018
```

query is-

```
   SELECT  `C_ID`,`dob` 
   FROM  `mf_customer_registration` 
   WHERE `ARN`='' order by date(`dob`) ASC
```

[image]

Comment: You would appear to be storing `dob` as a string rather than a date.  Fix the format of the column to use a date.

Comment: i know gordon its complicated format. but i have already max numbers of data in this format. could u help me how is it possible in this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your date sttroed in string format you have to convert it in date format using `STR_TO_DATE`

```
SELECT  `C_ID`,`dob` 
FROM  `mf_customer_registration` 
WHERE `ARN`='' order by STR_TO_DATE(`dob`,'%d-%b-%Y') ASC
```

Here

```
%d -> Day of the month, numeric (00..31)
%b -> Abbreviated month name (Jan..Dec)
%Y -> Year, numeric, four digits
```